# std::result_of for lvalue/rvalue arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I noticed this behavior of `std::result_of` when playing around:

```
struct Foo {
    int operator()(const int&) const { ... }
    char operator()(int&&) const { ... }
};

result_of_t<Foo(const int&)> a;  // int
result_of_t<Foo(int&&)>      b;  // char
result_of_t<Foo(int)>        c;  // char -- why?
```

Why does `std::result_of` prefer the function taking an rvalue reference for the third case?

Comment: What's the question? Why *not*? Clearly the second function is a better match (requiring one less conversion).

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you elaborate? The overload resolution rules always make my head ache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::result_of` when given non-reference parameters presumes they are rvalues.

In fact, `std::result_of_t<A(B)>` is the same as `std::result_of_t<A(B&&)>` in almost all cases.

You can see some [possibile implementations here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) if you want to see why.  Basically, `result_of_t<A(B)>` does a `decltype( std::declval<A>()(std::declval<B>()) )` (ignoring member function pointer cases), and a `B&&` rvalue reference and a temporary `B` will invoke the same overloads of any `operator()` on an `A`.

Comment: "in all cases" - close, but not quite.

Comment: @T.C. I cannot figure out a case that it won't match.  Even `template<class T> void operator()(T)` and `template<class T> void operator(T&&)` shouldn't distinguish?  Same with r/l value this... what am I missing?

Comment: In the first case, you get the fun adjustments applied to `B`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d50e88749850fc4 (Of course, it isn't `result_of`'s fault; the problem happens earlier, when the function type is formed...)

Answer (score 1):

There are [three primary value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (lvalue, prvalue and xvalue), and three [reference qualifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) (none, `&` and `&&`).

Clearly it makes sense that `&` should designate lvalue category and `&&` should designate xvalue; it follows that an omitted reference qualifier should designate prvalue.

Note that this is the same as you would get for a function with the corresponding return type:

```
int f(); // returns prvalue int
int& f(); // returns lvalue reference to int
int&& f(); // returns xvalue reference to int
```

And in your case:

```
const int& f();
int&& g();
int h();

decltype(Foo{}(f())) a;  // int
decltype(Foo{}(g())) b;  // char
decltype(Foo{}(h())) c;  // char
```

So you can see that `result_of` is just showing what `decltype` would tell you.